# What would be the most quick-installing and quick-booting desktop Linux for use in a VM exclusively for bank stuff?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, distributions

My bank has started harassing me by introducing "bugs" resulting in blank pages in Pale Moon. I thus cannot log in to it with Pale Moon, my only browser, anymore.

I cannot install spyware such as Chrome/Chromium/Firefox/Vivaldi/Brave/etc. on my main/host OS.

I'm therefore looking for the most quick-installing and quick-booting Linux desktop distro which I can use in VMware exclusively to do bank stuff in a "standard" browser in which the bank website actually works.

I believe I cannot use a "live" distro (no installation) because then I would have no way to bookmark the bank website in the browser and would have to type it in every time, or copy and paste the URL over into the VM. But maybe this is the best solution after all? Or maybe such a "live" distro can somehow be configured?

What do you recommend which is as simple as possible to set up and loads very quickly, so that it will almost be like I'm launching a browser on my host OS?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I cannot use a "live" distro (no installation) because then I would have no way to bookmark the bank website in the browser and would have to type it in every time, or copy and paste the URL over into the VM.

The hassle of firing up a VM just to run a web browser is already egregious enough, typing a bank URL in the URL bar shouldn't be a concern.

> Or maybe such a "live" distro can somehow be configured?

All live distros can be reconfigured. Consult with your favourite distro LiveCD/remastering howto/guides which are distro specific.

> What do you recommend which is as simple as possible to set up and loads very quickly, so that it will almost be like I'm launching a browser on my host OS?

You could run a "bad" web browser under a separate user account or under `firejail`. In case you're running a fully updated Linux distro, you should be safe to run even untrusted code.

> What do you recommend which is as simple as possible to set up and loads very quickly, so that it will almost be like I'm launching a browser on my host OS?

`firejail` will allow you to achieve exactly that: a near native speed of execution and fine-grained control over permissions.